# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

Currently, this is my code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as ' f'{bot.user}')

@bot.command()
async def vclist(ctx):
  channel = bot.get_channel('944509044599697458')
  userids = []
  users = channel.members
  for member in users:
    userids.append(member.id)
    print(userids)
```

When I try to run it I keep getting this Error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'
```

and I can't seem to solve it, can anyone help me?

Comment: Apparently `channel is None`. I've never used this API but according to the docs https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel `get_channel` seems to take an integer not a string. Tried that?

Answer (score 0):

`get_channel` takes an integer, not a string.

**ALSO:**
Make sure you have `guild` intents enabled otherwise `get_channel` will still return `None`. If you need help understanding/setting-up intents see the [docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)